# Trouble installing Meteor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, curl, meteor

I'm having trouble installing Meteor on Ubuntu 14.04. I searched through previous answers, but none had the same problem that I'm having.

When I run the command given on the meteor website:

```
sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

I get the following message:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6121    0  6121    0     0   6571      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6567
Downloading Meteor distribution

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Installation failed.enter code here
```

I already ensured that curl was installed and ran `sudo update-ca-certificates`, `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, all of which helped previous posters. I also tried `wget https://install.meteor.com/`, which gives me:

```
--2015-05-10 10:05:11--  https://install.meteor.com/
Resolving install.meteor.com (install.meteor.com)... 54.243.218.35, 54.83.1.203, 107.21.116.12, ...
Connecting to install.meteor.com (install.meteor.com)|54.243.218.35|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

    [ <=>                                   ] 6,121       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-05-10 10:05:13 (153 MB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [6121]
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try installation with `--insecure` option

```
curl --insecure https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

You also do not need to install meteor as root. If you want to use it as normal user, just install as that. You will automatically get a prompt for `sudo` when meteor install the starter script to `/usr/local/bin/meteor`

Good Luck
Tom

EDIT: if that does not work either:

```
# check your environment
echo $(test -d /etc/pki/tls/certs)$?
```

If the result is "1" than that is missing on your system. Try to solve:

```
# create missing directory
sudo mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs

# link ca-certificates 
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

After that just try to install meteor as documented

```
# install
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```